# Android GcmListenerService parallel?

Tags: android, multithreading, service, parallel-processing, google-cloud-messaging

Does the `GcmListenerService` process the `gcm` messages in parallel or sequentially? I know that normal `Android services` run in the main thread. But does that also apply to `GcmListenerService`?

Comment: Based on Official Google Documentation, for each sender ID, GCM allows 1000 connections in parallel. For more details, click here: https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/ccs

Comment: So they allow up to 1000 connections in parallel, but what does GcmListenerService does? Does it process the messages it gets in parallel?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GcmListenerService processes messages in parallel in background threads, see the note in [the docs](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/gcm/GcmListenerService) that methods are invoked asynchronously. So you are able to do blocking tasks in onMessageReceived() without worrying about blocking future messages.

Comment: Odd that it extends `Service` instead of `IntentService`. I thought it'd be in the main thread because of it's inheritance.